# How can I update elementary OS without interrupting NVIDIA driver?

Tags: updates, nvidia

I have an NVIDIA GTX 1050 TI GPU on my elementary OS. I once tried an OS update via AppCenter. Then reboot it. Then my NVIDIA driver isn't working properly. So I have to reinstall the NVIDIA driver again. I use the NVIDIA driver from [the NVIDIA site](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/156086/en-us).

I don't use a special driver from AppCenter because there is a problem with my Autodesk Maya application. But with this driver, there are no problems.

So, how so that when I update this OS, my NVIDIA driver is not interrupted?

Answer (score 1):

I use a Dell XPS 15 9560 with Integrated intel + GTX 1050. I've learn not to mess with other NVIDIA driver rather than what appears available in AppCenter. My recommendation to you would be the following:

1) Uninstall any NVIDIA thingy you might have in your system.
2) Completely update elementaryOS to the latest.
3) Check which Kernel version you're running (doing 'uname -r' from a terminal does the trick).
-At this point make sure you're running the latest curated kernel for eOS which is 5.xxxx (I run a custom 5.3.13 like a charm but let's do this the simple way).

If you're running the latest elementary+5.x kernel then:

4) Install the latest nvidia driver available from AppCenter (Currently I'm running 435.21 with zero issues).

I know you mention something about Autodesk and AppCenter's NVidia driver, but I'm betting money on a kernel/driver issue. If done this way, it should give you what you need (hopefully).

let me know! I'll try to run Maya myself to see if I have any issues or not.
-Aldo

Comment: I've tried to install Nvidia from AppCenter again days ago. Still have the issues with Autodesk Maya. Color Management thing problems and not load the OpenCL. Some article says it causes by the driver. And someone though me to just use Nvidia Proprietary driver to make it work. I thought maybe it is because a permission problem with the driver from appcenter.
So, the most important for me is Autodesk Maya and Nvidia work properly on my PC. I work with those app. But the problem always come after updating this OS. I hope you can help me with another solution after you tried to running Maya.